# How to add total Hours for a Ticket including all child tickets?

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion

My general problem is I have a system of ticket where a Ticket can any number of child tickets, and each child can in turn have children to any depth. I have seen some 7 layers deep, some 1 layer deep. There is no requirement a ticket has a parent after all it might be the top level of other tickets or it might have no children or parents.

I am trying to calculate the hours worked against the tickets to include all children tickets + actual ticket. So for example Ticket 30 has no direct hours, but all tickets role up to it so it should have all the hours. Similar other layer have children tickets and hours so they should show, maybe they have 8 direct hours, their children have sum(16) so 8 direct hours + sum(16) = 24 total hours.

My first thought was "recursive cte easy" but then realized you cannot do either an outer join and an aggregate in recursion which you would need both of. My next thought was some type of loop with a set cycle like do 20 times and just hope there is never more depth than 20. However this is for a View and I do not actually know the depth.

```
  drop table if exists tickets
    CREATE TABLE tickets (
      ticketid INT,
  parentID INT
);

drop table if exists Hours

CREATE TABLE Hours (
  ticketid INT,
  hours INT
)

insert into  tickets  (ticketid ,  parentID )
values 
('1','6')
,('2','7')
,('3','8')
,('4','9')
,('5','10')
,('6','18')
,('7','19')
,('8','20')
,('9','21')
,('10','22')
,('11','23')
,('12','18')
,('13','19')
,('14','20')
,('15','21')
,('16','22')
,('17','23')
,('18','24')
,('19','25')
,('20','26')
,('21','27')
,('22','28')
,('23','29')
,('24','30')
,('25','30')
,('26','30')
,('27','30')
,('28','30')
,('29','30')
,('30','')

insert into hours (ticketid, hours) 
values 
('22','4')
,('28','1')
,('15','1')
,('23','2')
,('16','1')
,('7','4')
,('12','2')
,('28','3')
,('19','4')
,('14','1')
,('10','4')
,('18','5')
,('3','2')
,('6','3')
,('7','2')
,('23','5')
,('26','2')
,('26','4')
,('14','2')
,('6','1')
,('24','4')
,('4','1')
,('4','5')
,('25','2')
,('0','4')
,('8','4')
,('20','2')
,('19','1')
,('6','1')
,('24','1')
,('26','2')
,('15','5')
,('1','1')
,('2','5')
,('3','2')
,('4','1')
,('5','2')
,('6','3')
,('7','2')
,('8','5')
,('9','2')
,('10','5')
,('11','1')
,('12','3')
,('13','2')
,('14','5')
,('15','3')
,('16','2')
,('17','4')
,('18','1')
,('19','3')
,('20','2')
,('21','5')
,('22','3')
,('23','4')
,('24','4')
,('25','3')
,('26','2')
,('27','3')
,('28','5')
,('29','4')
,('30','0')
,('1','2')
,('2','1')
,('3','5')
,('4','4')
,('5','3')
,('6','2')
,('7','1')
,('8','2')
,('9','5')
,('10','4')
,('11','1')
,('12','5')
,('13','2')
,('14','1')
,('15','5')
,('16','5')
,('17','4')
,('18','1')
,('19','1')
,('20','5')
,('21','3')
,('22','5')
,('23','3')
,('24','4')
,('25','4')
,('26','2')
,('27','2')
,('28','1')
,('29','1')
,('30','0')

;
with tot_hours as (
  select t.ticketid, 
         t.parentid,
  sum(hours) tot_hours
 from tickets t
  left join hours h
   on t.ticketid = h.ticketid
  group by t.ticketid
  
  UNION ALL 
  
select t.parentid, 
       ti.parentid,
       sum(tot_hours) tot_hours
 from tot_hours t
 left join tickets ti
   on t.parentid = ti.ticketid
 join hours h
   on t.ticketid = h.ticketid
      group by t.parentid  
      
      ) 
    
select tot.* ,sum(h.hours) 
from tot_hours tot
left join hours h
on tot.ticketid = h.ticketid 
group by tot.ticketid
,tot.parentid
,tot.tot_hours
```

The goal would be something like the below. With the Ticket, direct hour and total hours.
[image]

An extremely over simplified not using the data above would look something like this
[image]

Comment: Including the expected results for your query would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basing the code on your data, i came up with this:

```sql
WITH    CTE_TREE AS (
        SELECT  parentid AS parentid, ticketid AS children
        FROM    tickets t
        WHERE   parentID <> 0
        UNION
        SELECT  parentid, NULL
        FROM    tickets
        WHERE   parentID <> 0
        UNION
        SELECT  ticketid, NULL
        FROM    tickets
    )
    ,   CTE_TRAVERSE AS (
        SELECT  parentid AS mainId, children AS nextParent
        FROM    CTE_TREE
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  t.mainId, tree.children
        FROM    CTE_TREE tree
        INNER JOIN CTE_TRAVERSE t
            ON  t.nextParent = tree.parentid
        WHERE   tree.children <> ''
    )
    SELECT  t.MainID
    ,   SUM(CASE WHEN t.nextparent IS NULL THEN h.Hours END) AS Direct_hours
    ,   SUM(h.Hours) AS Total_hours
    FROM    CTE_TRAVERSE t
    INNER JOIN Hours h
        ON  h.ticketid = t.nextparent
        OR  (h.ticketid = t.mainID AND t.nextparent IS NULL)
    GROUP BY t.mainId
```

The code is a bit busy, but the main idea is to reverse your structure so it looks like: parent_id => children, instead of children => parent, because you're interested in top level information.

CTE_TREE contains all combination of tickets while CTE_TRAVERSE goes from parent to the children recursively, while keeping the "top" parentid as main id. It's important to keep a "master" row of each ticket without children, so it's easy to join the Hours table later.

Finally, we join against the Hours on either child rows (nextparent) or the master row with no children.

Outputs:

| MainID | Direct_hours | Total_hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 3 |
| 2 | 6 | 6 |
| 3 | 9 | 9 |
| 4 | 11 | 11 |
| 5 | 5 | 5 |
| 6 | 10 | 13 |
| 7 | 9 | 15 |
| 8 | 11 | 20 |
| 9 | 7 | 18 |
| 10 | 13 | 18 |
| 11 | 2 | 2 |
| 12 | 10 | 10 |
| 13 | 4 | 4 |
| 14 | 9 | 9 |
| 15 | 14 | 14 |
| 16 | 8 | 8 |
| 17 | 8 | 8 |
| 18 | 7 | 30 |
| 19 | 9 | 28 |
| 20 | 9 | 38 |
| 21 | 8 | 40 |
| 22 | 12 | 38 |
| 23 | 14 | 24 |
| 24 | 13 | 43 |
| 25 | 9 | 37 |
| 26 | 12 | 50 |
| 27 | 5 | 45 |
| 28 | 10 | 48 |
| 29 | 5 | 29 |
| 30 | 0 | 252 |

Btw, i think your calculation for 29 is wrong, because it should be a sum of 11,17, 23, 29, seems you missed to add the 11 ticket.

Comment: Thank you Siggemannen, this thing had me spinning. I knew it must be possible without some silly game of loops, but wasn't sure what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution proposed by Siggemannen is optimal in terms of code complexity.
I voted for his answer.
I will propose a similar solution. It might also be interesting to watch it.
First, group hours by ticket id and then join with tickets. This should significantly reduce the recursive part of the query.

```
with th as(
select ticketid,sum(hours) self_h
from hours
group by ticketid
)
,tph as(
select t.ticketid,t.parentid ,self_h
from tickets t
left join th on th.ticketid=t.ticketid
)
,r as(
  select 0 lvl,ticketid mainid
     ,parentid
     ,ticketid childid
     ,self_h, 0 child_h
  from tph
  union all
  select lvl+1 lvl,mainid
     ,t.parentid
     ,t.ticketid
     ,0 self_h,t.self_h child_h
  from tph t inner join r on r.childid=t.parentid
)
select mainid,sum(self_h)+sum(child_h) total_h
  ,sum(self_h) self_h
  ,sum(child_h) child_h
  ,max(lvl) deep
  ,string_agg(iif(childid<>mainid,cast(childid as varchar),null),',') 
          within group (order by lvl desc) childList
  ,string_agg(iif(childid<>mainid,cast(child_h as varchar),cast(self_h as varchar)),'+')
                within group ( order by lvl desc)  sumList
from r
group by mainid
```

Output

| mainid | total_h | self_h | child_h | deep | childList | sumList |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 3 | 0 | 0 | null | 3 |
| 2 | 6 | 6 | 0 | 0 | null | 6 |
| 3 | 9 | 9 | 0 | 0 | null | 9 |
| 4 | 11 | 11 | 0 | 0 | null | 11 |
| 5 | 5 | 5 | 0 | 0 | null | 5 |
| 6 | 13 | 10 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 3+10 |
| 7 | 15 | 9 | 6 | 1 | 2 | 6+9 |
| 8 | 20 | 11 | 9 | 1 | 3 | 9+11 |
| 9 | 18 | 7 | 11 | 1 | 4 | 11+7 |
| 10 | 18 | 13 | 5 | 1 | 5 | 5+13 |
| 11 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 0 | null | 2 |
| 12 | 10 | 10 | 0 | 0 | null | 10 |
| 13 | 4 | 4 | 0 | 0 | null | 4 |
| 14 | 9 | 9 | 0 | 0 | null | 9 |
| 15 | 14 | 14 | 0 | 0 | null | 14 |
| 16 | 8 | 8 | 0 | 0 | null | 8 |
| 17 | 8 | 8 | 0 | 0 | null | 8 |
| 18 | 30 | 7 | 23 | 2 | 1,6,12 | 3+10+10+7 |
| 19 | 28 | 9 | 19 | 2 | 2,7,13 | 6+9+4+9 |
| 20 | 38 | 9 | 29 | 2 | 3,8,14 | 9+11+9+9 |
| 21 | 40 | 8 | 32 | 2 | 4,9,15 | 11+7+14+8 |
| 22 | 38 | 12 | 26 | 2 | 5,10,16 | 5+13+8+12 |
| 23 | 24 | 14 | 10 | 1 | 11,17 | 2+8+14 |
| 24 | 43 | 13 | 30 | 3 | 1,6,12,18 | 3+10+10+7+13 |
| 25 | 37 | 9 | 28 | 3 | 2,7,13,19 | 6+9+4+9+9 |
| 26 | 50 | 12 | 38 | 3 | 3,8,14,20 | 9+11+9+9+12 |
| 27 | 45 | 5 | 40 | 3 | 4,9,15,21 | 11+7+14+8+5 |
| 28 | 48 | 10 | 38 | 3 | 5,10,16,22 | 5+13+8+12+10 |
| 29 | 29 | 5 | 24 | 2 | 11,17,23 | 2+8+14+5 |
| 30 | 252 | 0 | 252 | 4 | 5,4,1,3,2,6 ,12,7,13,8,14,9 ,15,11,17,10,16,22 ,21,20,19,18,23,24 ,25,26,27,28,29 | 5+11+3+9+6+10 +10+9+4+11+9+7 +14+2+8+13+8+12 +8+9+9+7+14+13 +9+12+5+10+5+0 |

[Fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/npVzfVqq)

Comment: Thanks ValNik I will take a look at this see how it works.